# why don't we use "is" in here?

Tags: sentence-construction

We can detect these lower-energy photons using what **are (is?)** sometimes called night-vision goggles or cameras.

Why don't we use "is" instead of "are" behind "what" of the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use 'are' (the plural form of the verb 'to be') because 'goggles or cameras' is a plural phrase. I can climb higher with a thing called a ladder; we can kill people with things called weapons.

Comment: Did you notice that in the quoted sentence, the subject of "are" is "what," not "we"? The "we" is not relevant here.